# What is the best data structure to store road network data

Tags: matlab, data-structures, spatial-index

I am working on a map-matching/trajectory matching project. What I am unsure after reading a number of research papers is what is the most efficient data structure to store the road network (described by a weighted directed graph) so as to facilitate real time searching (Fast). I am getting things like grids, MTrees, Quadtrees...do I need a database in the backend for these. I am working on MATLAB at the moment but can shift languages. What are the programming languages used in actual satellite navigators.

Help will be much appreciated

Comment: Yes..I have the MAtlab Mapping Toolbox

Comment: Without a detailled description of the data, and a proper definition of best, a concise answer does not appear to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are many such index structures like [K-D Trees](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FK-d_tree&ei=XzFXUob7EqmCjALIooGICQ&usg=AFQjCNGjrg6UghoWevl-OMsBQrJ7ChBM1w&sig2=h4HTl_Q4J9zZPUaYl-fL3g&bvm=bv.53899372,d.cGE), [R-Trees](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDwQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FR-tree&ei=HzNXUrC9IYKcjAK584G4CA&usg=AFQjCNHxXsWAhIh51Neg1_-NbPzDUCn0Ng&sig2=EykfAxuPdZ9MDpvGMI894Q&bvm=bv.53899372,d.cGE) etc. that can be built on the data that you store on the database. You can store your data on SQL Server and use these indexes. You might also want to take a look at SQL Server Spatial tools that helps to perform Spatial queries on your data.